# iOS Branch.io deeplink doesn't open the installed app and always redirects to app store except for the first link shared

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, deep-learning, branch.io

I'm using **Branch SDK** for creating deep links and sharing them. If the app is installed, the link should've open it. But the link is always redirecting to app store **except for the first link**. **The first link** opens the app perfectly **but** any new links always redirect to the app store even though the app is installed.

I followed all the steps from documentation, https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/
but still no luck. Can you please help me find the problem?

Comment: include some code bro

Comment: codes are same as from documentation except with specific values.

Comment: @sanjaykmwt sir, please provide me any good tutorial for iOS objective c for branch deeplinking.

Answer (score 2):

Jackie from Branch here:

Here's our iOS integration guide you're looking for. We have code samples both in Swift and Objective C: https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/

If you continue to experience issues after you have gone through the troubleshoot docs(https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/#troubleshoot-issues), could you please reach out to us at integrations@branch.io with the following details?

- Your Branch app ID
- Detailed steps to reproduce
- Links where the issue can be seen

Thanks!